# How to fill a datatable for specified datacolumn and datarow?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

```
 foreach(string dmName in datamodelsLoc) {
   tablesAndColumns.Columns.Add(dmName, typeof(string));
   List<String> columnNames = columnNamesList(req, dmName);
   foreach (string cols in columnNames) {
     var row = tablesAndColumns.NewRow();
     row[columnCount] = cols;
     tablesAndColumns.Rows.Add(row);
   }

   columnCount++;
 }
 var tabletest = tablesAndColumns;
```

> 

```
   public static List<String> columnNamesList (upa_request req, string tablename) {
        List<String> listacolumnas = new List<String>();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cnStr(req))){
            using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand()){
                command.CommandText = "USE ["+ req.processId +"] select c.name from sys.columns c inner join sys.tables t on t.object_id = c.object_id and t.name = '"+tablename+"' and t.type = 'U'";
                connection.Open();
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
                    while (reader.Read()) {
                        listacolumnas.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                    }
                }
            }
            connection.Close();
        }


        return listacolumnas;
    }
```

Hi Guys, I have this loop to add columns from the list DatamodelsLoc and then for each column added, add the specific data from columnNamesList.

The output i m getting is that its filling the first row but not the second one. It doen't even throw any exception or any error. 
Could you please help me?

Comment: What is `columnNamesList()` doing?  If it's returning only one string, the problem may be there.

Comment: No sir, it's a methode returning a list of strings. Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: That may be the return type, but I'm referring to the actual value of the return.  The problem suggests that your method is only grabbing one string, putting it in your list, and returning it.